# Make failing when trying to build Octave-4.0.0 from source

Tags: makefile, octave

The error message I'm getting is:-

```
Makefile:3060: warning: overriding recipe for target 'check'
Makefile:2415: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'check'
  GEN      run-octave
/bin/bash: ./build-aux/move-if-change: Permission denied
Makefile:3066: recipe for target 'run-octave' failed
make: *** [run-octave] Error 126
```

I've tried sudo make (because of the permission thing) but it hasn't helped.

Comment: What does `ls -l ./build-aux/move-if-change` say? Did you do anything to the sources before trying to build them? Have you tried asking the Octave community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Closer inspection showed that most of the shell files in the source directory had "Forbidden" as their file permissions. Rather than reset them manually I did

```
make clean
```

deleted the source file and downloaded a new source file and the installation went without a hiccup.

The old source file was from a home partition backup after updating my operating system from LMDE1 to LMDE2. I can only assume that this whole backing up process was the root cause of the problem.